# Py to exe pyinstaller import errors

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-module

Im trying to convert a single file python script/project into an exe using pyinstaller
Even thought pyinstaller converts the script the .exe will run and throw this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
ImportError
[16676] Failed to execute script main
```

I'm stumped , through my trial and erroring i figured that when i replace pynput with a module like random 
 the convertion works fine , but i need it to work with pynput 
please help , thanks in advance!

Comment: pls put the complete command you have used along with parameters. for example `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed my_app.py` seems like it did not import all the modules.

Comment: `pyinstaller my_app.py -F` 
 i also tried to do this
`pyinstaller my_app.py -F --hiddenimport=pynput`
.and this
`pyinstaller my_app.py -F -p C:\pathToVenv\Lib\site-packages` 
by the way if that helps this is a pycharm project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authors made some changes which i feel broke the reference.
so instead of package it is referring file.

```
- backend = backend(__package__)
+ backend = backend(__name__)
```

pls try to downgrade your package and check that your app still works.

```
pip install pynput==1.6.8
```

then your command like following would work.

```
pyinstaller --onefile   build_pkg_for.py
```

Comment: Wow that actually fixxed the problem , thank you very much!! So to understand the problem , is it a pyinstaller problem or a pynput problem , just so if it happens again with a diffrent module i can do the same thing :)

Comment: it depends on whose user base is large :) at this moment I would say the latest version of pynput and pyinstaller are incompatible.